# jQuery mouse enter and mouse leave not updating class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a background image on a div and when the user mouses over the image, a div will appear with relevant info. I have it appear on mouse enter and fadeOut() on mouse leave. Each time it updates a class called "slide". However, it will only update the class once. It works perfectly fine just using it without the extra fadeOut() function. What am I missing?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fashion-img1").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".fashion-img-content1").toggleClass("slide");
  });

  $(".fashion-img1").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".fashion-img-content1").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("slide");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.fashion-img-content1,
.fashion-img-content2,
.fashion-img-content3 {
  margin: 40% 15% 0 10%;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #333;
}
.slideanim {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.slide {
  animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  visibility: visible;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row slideanim img-row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="fashion-img1">
      <div class="fashion-img-content1 text-center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        <p>Tellus purus praesent orci, integer sapien a lorem orci augue, arcu at eleifend vestibulum quam, provident rutrum ut ridiculus duis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="fashion-img2">
      <div class="fashion-img-content2 text-center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        <p>Tellus purus praesent orci, integer sapien a lorem orci augue, arcu at eleifend vestibulum quam, provident rutrum ut ridiculus duis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="fashion-img3">
      <div class="fashion-img-content3 text-center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        <p>Tellus purus praesent orci, integer sapien a lorem orci augue, arcu at eleifend vestibulum quam, provident rutrum ut ridiculus duis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `visibility:hidden` is not the same as `display:none` nor `opacity:0` either

Answer (score -1):

Div ID's need to be unique whereas Div Classes are generic. You are currently giving your classes unique names which is why your code isn't properly targeting DIV's.

In addition using toggleClass is re-toggling the class each time you leave and reenter - hence effectively undoing the action. So this has been changed to addClass and removeClass for clarity.

Finally, in using fadeOut you are fading a div's opacity to zero, and then applying CSS `display:none;` which removes it from display. This is different to CSS `visibility: none;` as @Daniel points out in comments.

**UPDATE**: snippet updated to reflect info div fading in and out

The following snippet illustrates the class switching and appropriate use of classnames:

```js
$(".fashion-img").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).find(".fashion-img-content").addClass("slide");
  $(this).find(".info").fadeIn();
});

$(".fashion-img").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find(".fashion-img-content").removeClass("slide");
  $(this).find(".info").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.fashion-img-content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.info {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.slide {
  background: #09f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row slideanim img-row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="fashion-img">
      <div class="fashion-img-content text-center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        <p class="info">Tellus purus praesent orci, integer sapien a lorem orci augue, arcu at eleifend vestibulum quam, provident rutrum ut ridiculus duis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="fashion-img">
      <div class="fashion-img-content text-center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        <p class="info">Tellus purus praesent orci, integer sapien a lorem orci augue, arcu at eleifend vestibulum quam, provident rutrum ut ridiculus duis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="fashion-img">
      <div class="fashion-img-content text-center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        <p class="info">Tellus purus praesent orci, integer sapien a lorem orci augue, arcu at eleifend vestibulum quam, provident rutrum ut ridiculus duis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Having a div with a unique class name doesn't mean you can't select it by that class name.  You should remove that from your answer as it's both incorrect and confusing.

Comment: For sure however in this case the mouseenter and mouseleave functions would need to be rewritten for each variation of the classname, in addition the CSS styling would be less efficient: `.fashion-img-content1, .fashion-img-content2, .fashion-img-content3 {` would become `.fashion-img-content {` in the CSS, allowing for further content later.